# What is $C_4$ + two "ears" called?

Tags: graphs, terminology

A graph with $C_3$ + 3 "ears" is called a [net graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NetGraph.html).

[image]

In general, $C_n$ + $n$ pendant vertices are called [sunlet graphs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SunletGraph.html).

Is there a name for 4-sunlet graph minus two pendant vertices?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [ISGCI](http://www.graphclasses.org/smallgraphs.html#nodes6) this graph is known as "A".

Looking at some references, it also seems that there is really no common well-known name.